# Can Liquid be used to quickly add the CSS styling of a custom class to text?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is there some way to quickly add CSS styling, e.g. via a CSS class, using Liquid (in a markdown document generated with Jekyll)?

I'd like to be able to write something like

```
blah blah words {% someclass | words styled by class someclass %} some
more words.
```

I have the sense that something like this is possible, from snippets I've seen somewhere in passing, but for all my googling now, can't find how to do it (or if it is indeed possible). I'm almost totally new to Liquid.

I know that I can do the following

```
blah unstyled words

{:.someclass}
words to be styled by CSS of someclass

blah unstyled (well, body- and p-styled) words
```

to create a paragraph (due to markdown) with class applied, e.g. `<p class="sometag"> words to be styled by CSS of someclass</p>`, with the intended content enclosed.

Being able to change the element from `<p>` to `<span>` would be sufficient to achieve my goals.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can help you. For example, imagine that in the markdown file we want to insert a bold red `<H2>` title  and a paragraph `<p>` with bold green text using a custom tag.

You can do something like this: in the `_include` directory of your Jekyll project, create a file without extension called `mytag`. Inside the `mytag` file enter the code below and save it.

File `mytag` :

```yaml
{% if include.h2 %}
{% capture mystyle %}
<h2 style="color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em;"> {{ include.h2 }} </h2>
{% endcapture %}

{{ mystyle }}
{% endif %}



{% if include.p %}
{% capture mystyle %}
<p style="color: green; font-weight: bold;"> {{ include.p }} </p>
{% endcapture %}

{{ mystyle }}
{% endif %}
```

Now in your `.md` file you can write the code below to have a bold red `<H2>` title:

```yaml
{% include mytag h2="My title h2" %}
```

or you can write the code below to have a paragraph `<p>` with green bold text:

```yaml
{% include mytag p="I'm a green bold paragraph" %}
```

You can obviously personalize everything by entering the name of a class instead of the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler/cleaner solution, see the usage notes included.

Save this as `wrap.rb` and place in your plugins folder: `_plugins/wrap.rb`

```
# this plugin will wrap the content in the specified tag and and apply the specified classes
# 
# usage:
#   title = "A Guide to the Universe"
#   
#   {{ title | wrap: "h1", "title text-black" }}
#   output: <h1 class='title text-black'>A Guide to the Universe</h1>
#   
#   {{ title | wrap: "em" | wrap: "h1", "text-black" }}
#   output: <h1 class='text-black'><em>A Guide to the Universe</em></h1>

module Jekyll
  module Wrap

    def wrap(input, tag, classes=nil)
      if classes
        "<#{tag} class='#{classes}'>#{input}</#{tag}>"
      else
        "<#{tag}>#{input}</#{tag}>" 
      end 
    end

  end
end


Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::Wrap)
```